# Initialization pointer to pointer without losing reserved memeory

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I am working with a Binary Search Tree and i have a question about initialization without losing allocated memory.

```
/* newStructure.h */
typedef struct Item {
    int key;
    struct Item* LPtr;
    struct Item* RPtr;
} *tItem;
```

**Main code :**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "newStructure.h"

int main() {
    tItem* rootNode;
    if ( (rootNode = malloc(sizeof(struct Item))) == NULL ) 
        // Problem with malloc
        return 1;

    else {
        //Initialize node
        *rootNode = NULL; /* And here points my question */
    }
   // Code continues..
}
```

When i used `malloc()`, block of memory with size of `struct Item` was allocated and its address was stored in `*rootNode`, am i right ?
But when i initialize this node to `NULL` ( node doesn't contain any data yet ), i say that `*rootNode` contains `NULL` therefore i lost address of allocated memory block.
Or am i missing something in here?

Comment: Not directly related, but never use typedef to hide a pointer type. It doesn't make your code any clearer, instead it only adds confusion.

Comment: It's unclear why you need a pointer to a pointer here. Rewrite your code without the typedef and it should become clearer for you.

Answer (score 1):

> But when i initialize this node to `NULL` [...]

This is not the right way to initialize node to `NULL`

```
*rootNode = NULL;
```

You have assigned a block of `sizeof(struct Item)` to a field that is supposed to be a pointer to pointer, but then you treat it as a pointer, which is incorrect.

Your code does not need a pointer to pointer, a single-indirection pointer would be sufficient:

```
tItem rootNode; // You typedef-ed tItem is a pointer
if ( (rootNode = malloc(sizeof(struct Item))) == NULL ) {
    // Problem with malloc
    return 1;
} else {
    //Initialize node
    rootNode->key = 0;
    rootNode->LPtr = NULL;
    rootNode->RPtr = NULL;
}
```

Comment: But here `roodNode->key = 0;`, you didn't initialize node as empty, but you initialized as node with key value that equals to 0.. or do i just really don't get it..

Comment: @SevO `rootNode` is empty only as long as it's set to `NULL`. Once you allocate memory to it, it's no longer empty.

Comment: So my "initialization" could be used before allocation to be sure, that my pointer doesn't point somewhere, what could be missed if overwritten ?

Comment: @SevO If you declare `tItem* rootNode;` you can't dereference `rootNode` before allocating anything to it. However, since it's a pointer to a pointer, you'd have to allocate `sizeof(tItem)`, i.e. a pointer, not `sizeof(struct Item)`.